# How to fill Space in a html header?

Tags: html, css, header

I have bin trying to improve the header on my first selfmade website. The only thing I can't get right is to fill the remaining space with a color. Like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYzf8.png)

I've bin trying to do this by having a `div` fill the rest of the space, but couldn't get it to work.
I have read a lot of examples and similar questions, but none of the given answers seem to work for me.
The best I could manage is shown below, but I can't seem to get the hight right.

Here is my code so far:

```css
.header-container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 0;
}

.header-container a {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.header-container a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #279027;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 2px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.bar {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #279027;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="header-container">
      <a href="/">Home</a>
      <a href="/kontakt">Kontakt</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bar">test</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Make `.header-conatainer -> display:flex;` like below**

```css
.header-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

2. **Remove `float` from children.**
3. **Make `.bar` flex: 1;**

```css
.bar {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: cheers man, work like a charm. I tried somthing similar and it completly broke my layout, so I abandoned the display felx option. Looks like i should have spend more time there

Comment: Cool. I believe `flex` is the best tool for auto expansions.